# Counting things that aren't there?

Tags: java, math, count, bluej

When I compile this and input 5 evens or 5 odds the count comes out as 6 evens and 1 odd or 6 odds and 1 even. I think I did everything right please help its due tommorrow night. sorry at this point I'm writing this just to get it submitted.

```
    String oneString="";
    String twoString="";
    String threeString="";
    String fourString="";
    String fiveString="";

    int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0, zeroCount = 0;

    oneString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your first number");
    one = Integer.parseInt (oneString);
    while (one > 0) {
    one = one % 10;
    if (one%2==0) 
    {
       evenCount++;
    }
    else 
    { 
       oddCount++;
    }
    one = one / 10;
   }
   twoString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your second number");
    two = Integer.parseInt (twoString);

   while (two > 0) {
    two = two % 10;
    if (two%2==0) 
    {
       evenCount++;
    }
    else 
    { 
       oddCount++;
    }
    two = two / 10;
   }
   threeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your third number");
    three = Integer.parseInt (threeString);

   while (three > 0) {
    three = three % 10;
    if (three%2==0) 
    {
       evenCount++;
    }
    else 
    { 
       oddCount++;
    }
    three = three / 10;
   }
   fourString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your fourth number");
    four = Integer.parseInt (fourString);
   while (four > 0) {
    four = four % 10;
    if (four%2==0) 
    {
       evenCount++;
    }
    else 
    { 
       oddCount++;
    }
    four = four / 10;
   }
   fiveString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your fifth number");
    five = Integer.parseInt (fiveString);
    while (five > 0) 
   {
        five = five % 10;
        if (five%2==0) 
        {
           evenCount++;
        }
        else 
        { 
            oddCount++;
        }
        five = five / 10;
   }
   float count;
   count = evenCount++ + oddCount++;
   System.out.println(); 
   System.out.printf("Even: %d Odd: %d",evenCount, oddCount);
   float percentage;
   percentage = evenCount * 100 / count;
   System.out.println(" Percentage  of Even " + percentage);
   float oddpercentage;
   oddpercentage = oddCount * 100 / count;
   System.out.println(" Percentage  of Odd " + oddpercentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your problem is right here:

count = evenCount++ + oddCount++;

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
count = evenCount++ + oddCount++;
```

you are increasing both evenCount and oddCount. Instead, may I suggest the following:

```
count = evenCount + oddCount;
```

Also, why did you calculate the modulo with 10 first and then the modulo with 2?

Example:

```
five = five % 10;
if (five%2==0)
```

the first row of the example is useless, because:

```
((five % 10) % 2) == five % 2
```

So you do not need to calculate the modulo with ten for your five variables. It is worth than nothing.

Also, if something is not working and you are asking for help, then most probably you have made at least a mistake.